# Split Strings in java by words

Tags: java

How can I split the following word in to an array

`That's the code`

into

```
array
0 That
1 s
2 the
3 code
```

I tried something like this

```
String str = "That's the code";

        String[] strs = str.split("\\'");
        for (String sstr : strs) {
            System.out.println(sstr);
        }
```

But the output is

```
That
s the code
```

Comment: Why not use **space** when splitting? And take care of special characters like `'`.

Comment: Also when we say split a string to words, we mean **That's the code** to **That's**, **the** and **code**.

Comment: `That's the code` is equivalent to `That is the code`. I'm comparing sentence.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: why would we mean that? `That's` is two words: `That` and the contraction of `is` to `s`.

Comment: @JBNizet It depends what you mean by words. You are right when comparing sentence where treating `What's` to `What is`. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To specifically split on white space and the apostrophe:

```
public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] tokens = "That's the code".split("[\\s']");
        for(String s:tokens){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

or to split on any non word character:

```
public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] tokens = "That's the code".split("[\\W]");
        for(String s:tokens){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what the difference between [\\W] and [\\s']

Comment: `\\W` represents a non-word character which is any character that is not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character. `\\s` represents a white space, so tabs, spaces, line breaks, etc. If I were to add something in parens `()` to the String `\\W` would split on each paren, however the `\\s` version would not.

Comment: Do you now the runtime complexity for this method?

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I've found to split by words if your string contains accentuated letters is :

```
String[] listeMots = phrase.split("\\P{L}+");
```

For instance, if your String is

```
String phrase = "Salut mon homme, comment ça va aujourd'hui? Ce sera Noël puis Pâques bientôt.";
```

Then you will get the following words (enclosed within quotes and comma separated for clarity) :

```
"Salut", "mon", "homme", "comment", "ça", "va", "aujourd", "hui", "Ce", 
"sera", "Noël", "puis", "Pâques", "bientôt".
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can split according to non-characters chars:

```
String str = "That's the code";
String[] splitted = str.split("[\\W]");
```

For your input, output will be:

```
That
s
the
code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split by a regex that would be one of the two characters - quote or space:

```
String[] strs = str.split("['\\s]");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split on non alphabetic chars

```
String str = "That's the code";
String[] strs = str.split("\\P{Alpha}+");
for (String sstr : strs) {
        System.out.println(sstr);
}
```

\P{Alpha} matches any non-alphabetic character and this is called POSIX character you can read more about it in [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) It is very useful. + indicates that we should split on any continuous string of such characters.

and the output will be

```
That
s
the
code
```

Comment: +1 for Unicode version but this code may be not very clear for someone new to regex so you probably should expand your answer a little.

Answer (score 1):

You should first replace the `'` with `" "` (blank space), using `str.replaceAll("'", " ")` and then you can split the string on the blank space separator, using `str.split(" ")`.You could alternatively use a regular expression to split on ' OR space.

Answer (score 0):

`split` uses regex and in regex `'` is not special character so you don't need to escape it with `\`. To represent whitespaces you can use `\s` (which in String needs to be written as `"\\s"`). Also to create set of characters you can use "OR" operator `|` like `a|b|c|d`, or just use character class `[abcd]` which means exactly the same as `(a|b|c|d)`.

To makes things simple you can use

```
String[] strs = str.split("'| ");
```

or

```
String[] strs = str.split("'|\\s");//to include all whitespaces
```

or

```
String[] strs = str.split("['\\s]");//equivalent of "'|\\s"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` in regular expression

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "That's the code";
        String[] strs = str.split("'|\\s");
        for (String sstr : strs) {
            System.out.println(sstr);
        }
   }
```

The string will be split by single quote (') or space. The single quote doesn't need to be escaped. The output would be

```
run:
That
s
the
code
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```