# split the sentence using a delimiter as a string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split a sentence using a string as a delimiter.

```
String sentence = "Java and Python are programming language. Unix and Windows are operating systems."
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(sentence, "and");
```

expected output is

```
Java
Python are programming language. Unix
Windows are operating systems.
```

But split occurs for each and every characters mentioned as a delimiter. Is there any way to use the string directly to split the sentence? also is there any way to use multiple strings as a delimiter?

Comment: Why don't you use Regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for `StringTokenizer` says that:

> Constructs a string tokenizer for the specified string. The *characters* in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens. Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

So basically, you can't use multi character delimiters.

An alternative is to use `String.split` or `Scanner`, both of which takes a regular expression as a delimiter. This gives you lots more flexibility.

The closest to `StringTokenizer` would be `Scanner`. Here is an example usage:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Your String to Tokenize");
scanner.useDelimiter("and");
scanner.next(); // "next" is basically string tokeniser's "nextToken"
```

You can use multiple things as delimiters by separating them with `|`, e.g.:

```
"and|or"
```

As I've said, another way is to use `String.split`. It returns an array of strings:

```
String[] result = "Your String to Tokenize".split("and");
```

Comment: Whoever down voted can you kind explain your reason for doing so, so that I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct behavior. If you read the documentation for [`Stringtokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you see that the delimiter argument is basically a list of characters that you want to split the input with. So each character in the string is treated as a separate delimiter.

To split a string using words as a delimiter you should use `.split()` and a regex as the delimiter. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728050/split-strings-in-java-by-words) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sentence = "Java and Python are programming language. Unix and Windows are operating systems.";

String removedAnd = sentence.replaceAll("^and$", "");

 System.out.println(removedAnd);
//Java  Python are programming language. Unix  Windows are operating systems.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Java and Python are programming language. Unix and Windows are operating systems.";
String tmp = s.replace("and", "\n");
System.out.println(tmp)
```

or you can use this code

```
String s = "Java and Python are programming language. Unix and Windows are operating systems.";
s = s.replace("and", "\n");
System.out.println(s);
```

if you don't want to create a new literal

And the output is:

```
Java 
 Python are programming language. Unix 
 Windows are operating systems.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this works just how you want it.

```
String sentence = "Java and Python are programming language. Unix and Windows are operating systems.";
String[] s = sentence.split("[\\]*sand[\\s]*");
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    System.out.println(s[i]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why the negative vote? I tested it. It works **JUST** how you want it.

Comment: If the sentence being parsed contained the word "brandy", you regex would split that into "br" and "y".
(Note: I did not down vote you)

Comment: also: "also is there any way to use multiple strings as a delimiter?" you didnt address this.

Comment: Okay. You're right. Edited. Check it out.

Comment: I just addressed one question. Besides, you shouldn't ask more than one question in one post in SO, anyway.

Comment: what if "and" is at the beginning of the sentence? at the end? embedded in a string like "brandy"? Has more than one adjacent whitespace character?

Comment: @mangotang I'm sure this would do the trick. See my edit.