# Split File after certain words limit in java

Tags: java, arrays, file

Hey Guys I want to split a file using java after certain number of words and divide it into large number of files with fix words limit.

Till now i have splitted file on counting lines.

```
`package fileSplitting;
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class Split {

    public Split() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try{  
              // Reading file and getting no. of files to be generated  
              String inputfile = "externalFiles/data.txt"; //  Source File Name.  
              double nol = 20.0; //  No. of lines to be split and saved in each output file.  
              File file = new File(inputfile);  
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);  
              int count = 0;  
              while (scanner.hasNextLine())   
              {  
               scanner.nextLine();  
               count++;  
              }  
              System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + count);     // Displays no. of lines in the input file.  

              double temp = (count/nol);    
              int temp1=(int)temp;  
              int nof=0;  
              if(temp1==temp)  
              {  
               nof=temp1;  
              }  
              else  
              {  
               nof=temp1+1;  
              }  
              System.out.println("No. of files to be generated :"+nof); // Displays no. of files to be generated.  

              //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

              // Actual splitting of file into smaller files  

              FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inputfile); DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);  

              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); String strLine;  

              for (int j=1;j<=nof;j++)  
              {  
                  System.out.println("No.of time I have entered  :"+j);
               FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter("splittedFiles/File"+j+".html");     // Destination File Location  
               BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);   
               for (int i=1;i<=nol;i++)  
               {  
                strLine = br.readLine();   
                if (strLine!= null)  
                {  
                 out.write(strLine);   
                 if(i!=nol)  
                 {  
                  out.newLine();  
                 }  
                }  
               }  
               out.close();  
              }  

              in.close();  
             }catch (Exception e)  
             {  
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
             }  

            }  


}
```

`

Now i have to do the same but after counting words.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried to do then? There are [lots of resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726023/split-string-into-individual-words-java) that tell you how to split strings into words. Where did you get stuck implementing this?

Comment: Am I mistaken in my understanding that this wall of code has very little to do with your actual question, which is "how do I tokenise a String?" - a question that has probably been asked a few hundred times on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Read characters from the file and split them on white space character as delimiter and count the words and based on the word cont write to a file.

---

FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("FILE PATH"));

```
    char [] charBuff = new char [1024];

    int eof = 0;
    int count2  = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    String [] words =  new String [1024];
    int wc = 0;
     while ( (eof = reader.read(charBuff)) >0)
     {
        char c=' ';

        char [] tmpChars = new char [256]; 
        while (count1 < charBuff.length)
        {
            c= charBuff[count1];

            if(Character.getType(c) == 15)
                break;

            if(c == ' ')
            {
                words [wc] =  new String(tmpChars,0,count2);

                //You can write the tmpChars to a file a file without converting it to a string

                FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(new File("DIR:\\FILE NAME"+wc+".txt"));

                fWriter.write(tmpChars);
                fWriter.close();

                wc++;
                count1++;
                count2 = 0;
                tmpChars = new char [256];
                continue;
            }   

            tmpChars [count2] = c;
            count2++;
            count1++;
        }
     }

     for(String i: words)
     {
         System.out.println("Word - "+i);
     }
```

---