# Text Search for words which contain another word when spelt backwards

Tags: java

I am building a program which allows you to upload a text file and then search for words which form different words when spelt backwards and forwards. This is what I have so far:

```
public class RWF extends Application {

private Window mainStage;
private FileChooser fileChooser;
private String path;
private File file;
public String x;
public TextArea textArea;
public Iterator m;
public String reversed;
public ArrayList al;
public String[] words1;
public String z;
public Object element;

public String text;
private String[] pa;
private String sa;
private Array palindromeArray;
private String longest;
public Button openButton2;
private StringBuilder stringBuilder;
private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
public StringBuilder sb;
private BufferedReader br;
private String[] xsplit;
private String[] xsplit2;
private String words;
private String word;
public String str;
public String str2;


public RWF(){

    sb = stringBuilder;
    str2 = "Hellow";


}


public void start(Stage stage) {

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setPrefColumnCount(100);
    textArea.setPrefRowCount(100);

    VBox vbox = new VBox(textArea);

    final Button openButton = new Button("Open a Text File");
    final Button openButton2 = new Button("Analyse Text File");
    Group root = new Group(openButton, openButton2, textArea);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
     fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
     fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
             new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"),
             new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"));



    openButton.setLayoutX(250);
    openButton.setLayoutY(220);
    openButton2.setLayoutX(150);
    openButton2.setLayoutY(120);
    textArea.setLayoutX(450);
    textArea.setLayoutY(320);
       stage.setTitle("Text Analyser");
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();

       openButton.setOnAction(
               new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {


                @Override
                   public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                       File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
                       if (file != null) {
                           try {
                            textArea.setText(readFile(file));
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       }


                }



                private String readFile(File file) throws IOException {



StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


                    text = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    sb1.append(text);

                    System.out.println(sb1);





                    String u = sb1.toString();
                    xsplit2 = u.split(u);
                    for (String words : xsplit2){
                        System.out.println(words);
                    }

                    StringBuilder t = sb1.reverse();    
                String x = t.toString();
            xsplit = x.split(x);
            for (String word : xsplit){
                System.out.println(word);
            }

            for (int i=0; i<xsplit2.length; i++){
                boolean found = false;
                for (int j=0; j<xsplit.length; j++){
                    if ((xsplit2[i]).equals(xsplit[j])){
           found = true;




           str = Arrays.toString(xsplit);
           str2 = Arrays.toString(xsplit2);


              java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get("Users/paulc/workspace5000/words.txt");
                byte[] readBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                String wordListContents = new String(readBytes, "UTF-8");
                String[] words = wordListContents.split("\n");
                Set wordsSet = new HashSet<>();
                Collections.addAll(wordsSet, words);

                if (wordsSet.contains(str) && wordsSet.contains(str2)){
                    textArea.appendText(str);
                }


 openButton2.setOnAction(
           new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {






            @Override
               public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.appendText(str2);
                    }

});
       }
                }
            }
            return str2;
                };
               });
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(args);


}



}
```

My question is how would you find if another word was in the file which was a different word backwards.

E.g. if the file had the word 'saw', how would I find if there was a separate word 'was' which is 'saw' backwards?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly. A palindrome is a word that is spelled the same backwards and forwards.

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to break your code into separate methods and how to use local variables. There is little reason to declare all of these variables as fields.

Answer (score 0):

Make additional string with whole text reversed, you can see here how to do that: [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Than split words from original string, like this: [Split string into individual words Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726023/split-string-into-individual-words-java)

And than I would search for splitted words in reversed string: [How to find a whole word in a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091057/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how would you find if another word was in the file which was a different word backwards.
>   E.g. if the file had the word 'saw', how would I find if there was a separate word 'was' which is 'saw' backwards?

You could follow this algorithm:

- Create an empty set of strings, to put words into it
- For each word in the text

  - Check if the reversed word is in the set, and act on the result accordingly
  - Add the word to the set

Watch out for uppercase/lowercase letters.
You might want to lowercase all words as you iterate over the input and store words in the set.