# String split special regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Im trying to tokenize a string input, but I cant get my head around how to do it.
The Idea is, to split the string into instances of alphabetical words and non alphabetical symbols.
For example the String `"Test, ( abc)"` would be split into `["Test" , "," , "(" , "abc" , ")" ].`

Right now I use this regular Expression:
`"(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[^a-zA-Z])"`
but it doesnt do what I want.

Any ideas what else I could use?

Comment: w* for alphanuméric group of characters

Answer (score 2):

I see that you want to group the alphabets (like Test and abc) but no grouping of the non-alphabetical characters. Also I see that you do not want to show space char. For this I will use **`"(\\w+|\\W)"`** after removing all spaces from the strings to match.

**Sample code**

```
String str = "Test, ( abc)";
str = str.replaceAll(" ",""); // in case you do not want space as separate char.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|\\W)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output**

`Test
,
(
abc
)`

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: He modified the code after I posted. Earlier the code did not cater for the non-alpha characters (his regex was **\\w+** only, which is not correct answer. The question was not the code itself but the regex used. The code was used to illustrate the regex.). I hope this clarifies @GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "I want to walk my dog, and why not?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|\\W)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Outputs:

```
I
want
to
walk
my
dog
,
and
why
not
?
```

\w can be used to match word characters ([A-Za-z0-9_]), so that punctuation is removed from the results

(Taken from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28257108/2419751))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> res(String a) {
        String[] tokens = a.split("\\s+");
        ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String token : tokens) {
            String[] alpha = token.split("\\W+");
            String[] nonAlpha = token.split("\\w+");
            for (String str : alpha) {
                if (!str.isEmpty()) strs.add(str);
            }
            for (String str : nonAlpha) {
                if (!str.isEmpty()) strs.add(str);
            }
        }
        return strs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the simplest form, split using

```
"(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[^\\sa-zA-Z])|(?<=[^\\sa-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])|\\s+"
```

Explained

```
    (?<= [a-zA-Z] )               # Letter behind
    (?= [^\sa-zA-Z] )             # not letter/wsp ahead
 |                              # or,
    (?<= [^\sa-zA-Z] )            # Not letter/wsp behind
    (?= [a-zA-Z] )                # letter ahead
 |                              # or,
    \s+                           # whitespaces (disgarded)
```